# data selected in spinner is not transferred the first time

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, spinner, android-spinner

A video showing the problem:
[video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KLgsKK7p6E7h8w4dKWZGuenZD44JBQ_4/view?usp=sharing)

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ActivityListBinding binding;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    PaketAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Paket> paketArrayList;
    String magaza;
    String name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityListBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = binding.getRoot();
        setContentView(view);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        paketArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new PaketAdapter(paketArrayList);
        binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


       Intent intent = getIntent();
       magaza = intent.getStringExtra("magaza");

       getData();
    }

    public void getData(){
        firebaseFirestore.collection(magaza).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                if (error!=null){
                    Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this,error.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if (value!=null){

                    for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot:value.getDocuments()){
                        Map<String,Object> data = documentSnapshot.getData();

                        name = (String) data.get("name");
                        String paketSayisi = (String) data.get("paketSayisi");
                        String angaryaSayisi = (String) data.get("angaryaSayisi");
                        //FieldValue tarih = (FieldValue) data.get("tarih");
                        //String magaza = (String) data.get("magaza");

                        Paket paket = new Paket(name,paketSayisi,angaryaSayisi);
                        paketArrayList.add(paket);

                    }
                }
            }
        }); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    public void delete(View view){

               for (int i=0;i<= paketArrayList.size();i++){

                   firebaseFirestore.collection(magaza).document(name).delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                       @Override
                       public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                           Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this,"SİLİNDİ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       }
                   }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                           Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this,e.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                       }
                   });
               }
```

in the application I made, the user selects the store from the spinner and in the other activity, the package information from that store appears. However, when I log in and switch to other activity, the data is not coming. When I go back and go again, the data appears. Does anyone know where I went wrong or what I should do?

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private ActivityLoginBinding binding;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    String magaza;
    Intent intenttoList;
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view  = binding.getRoot();
        setContentView(view);

        intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,ListActivity.class);

        Intent gelenintent = getIntent();
        String email =gelenintent.getStringExtra("email");

        if (email.equals("")){

        }else {
            binding.username.setText(email);
        }
        binding.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        intenttoList = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,ListActivity.class);
        magaza="";


        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.magazaList,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        binding.spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public void logIn(View view){

        if (magaza.equals("çöp")){
           Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"MAĞAZA SEÇMENİZ GEREKMEKTEDİR",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            String username = binding.username.getText().toString();
            String password = binding.passWord.getText().toString();

            firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username,password).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


        if (adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().equals("MAĞAZA SEÇİN")){

            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"MAĞAZA SEÇMENİZ GEREKLİDİR",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            magaza ="çöp";

        }else{
            magaza =adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            intent.putExtra("magaza",magaza);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you doing the transition from the spinner activity to another?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: I added the codes of the activity I switched to. The problem is, I select the store name in LoginActivity, log in and switch to ListActivity. I want to receive information about the store I selected in MainActivity. However, when I log in, the list is empty. When I go back and go to ListActivity again, the list comes up. Why doesn't it show up on first login?

Comment: @zartVader From where are you calling your `logIn` method?

Comment: If you ask the view, I call it with onclick method by button. I am sorry if I misunderstand  you because I am very start of developing.

Comment: @zartVader Are you clicking on this button after you have selected an item from the spinner?

Comment: Yes, in loginActivity I fill username and password then I choose store name at spinner and click login button. This button switch the activity to ListActivity which includes A recyclerView. In this point I want to see objects from Firestore database, but I don't. Then I click back on Android device and click button again I see the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username,password).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListActivity.class)
                intent.putExtra("magaza",magaza);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

In the ListActivity.class call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` inside the `addSnapshotListener` callback.

```
firebaseFirestore.collection(magaza).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
            if (error!=null){
                Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this,error.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else if (value!=null){

                for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot:value.getDocuments()){
                    Map<String,Object> data = documentSnapshot.getData();

                    name = (String) data.get("name");
                    String paketSayisi = (String) data.get("paketSayisi");
                    String angaryaSayisi = (String) data.get("angaryaSayisi");
                    //FieldValue tarih = (FieldValue) data.get("tarih");
                    //String magaza = (String) data.get("magaza");

                    Paket paket = new Paket(name,paketSayisi,angaryaSayisi);
                    paketArrayList.add(paket);
                    
                }
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I've already made this way but but still problem appears. I got a record about what problem is. So I am gonna edit my question.

Comment: @zartVader I have updated the answer but in the `ListActivity.class` you need to wait for some time so that the data is fetched and populated in the view.

Comment: Thanks, it was fixed when I used the 'adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();' in the right place.

Comment: @zartVader It would be nice if you could accept this answer as this would help others in the community.